Как настроить автозаполнение табличной части в 1С:Предприятие при выборе реквизита документа?
У меня есть два документа с идентичной табличной частью: "ЗаказПокупателя" и "РасходнаяНакладная". При выборе реквизита "Заказы" в документе "РасходнаяНакладная", который является ссылкой на "ЗаказПокупателя", табличная часть должна автоматически заполняться данными из соответствующей табличной части выбранного заказа. При разработке проекта на платформе 1С возникла необходимость автоматического заполнения табличной части документа данными из заказа. Я новичок в 1С и сталкиваюсь с этой задачей впервые.


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Исправил вопрос, спасибо

На Форме, у поле реквизита Заказы есть событие ПриИзменении возникает когда пользователь заполняет этот реквизит. Создайте процедуру события, внитри процедуры напишите код заполнения данными..

Я создал событие ПриИзменении, поискал в интернете, попользовался нейросетью не помогло, можете помочь с кодом для автозаполнения, в вопрос я добавил картинку конфигурации

Не видно какого типа реквизит Заказы (предполагаю ДокументСсылка.ЗаказПокупателя) код получения данных при этом будет выглядеть примерно так:
_Заказ = Заказы.ПолучитьОбъект();
Для каждого _стр из _Заказ.ПереченьНоменклатуры Цикл
// _стр.Товар - Номенклатура из документа ЗаказПокупателя
